# How to get common values from two different maps in the fastest possible way?

Tags: java

i have two hash-maps. I want to find the values that are common to both the maps. One way is to iterate through the first map,get the value and use that value to match it with the values of other map through iteration. But this takes lot of time. Is there any other way to find the common values in the fastest possible way??

Comment: Fast as execution time or fast as smaller amount of code? Because you can't get the intersection faster than at least enumerating all the values of one of the maps.

Comment: @Tudor is right, none of the answers below will be faster in terms of time.  Any solution would have to iterate through one map and lookup in the other.  One optimization would be to iterate through the smaller map but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

`firstMap.keySet().retainAll(secondMap.keySet())` does what you want.

I am still not sure that this is the really fastest way. Probably if you can control the population of these 2 maps you can create third map that will accumulate shared keys during the data population?

Answer (score 0):

haven't tried this , and I am not sure whether its going to be faster or not , but you can consider converting HashMaps to HashSets and then call Set1.retainAll(Set2)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a very old post but if anyone else is looking for the answer for where values specifically have to match up you can do something like this

```
map1.entrySet().retainAll(map.entrySet());
```

If you use keySet() you'll retain common keys which has it's own use but if you want to match keys AND values, use entrySet().